# Highlight text in Windows 8 TextBox

Tags: c#, textbox, windows-8, windows-runtime

I'm looking for a way to highlight (not select) words based on search terms inside a `Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TextBox` control.

There doesn't seem to any way to override the text rendering behaviour? Can this be done with the textbox control?

Edit:
I was originally trying to use the RichEditBox but was having a problem with being able to paste in formatted text which I was trying to prevent (the only event I can clear the formatting on is TextChanged which seems a little late). I also really need more control over the rendering of the highlights

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Textboxes are very limited in regards to formatting and text selection.

You might want to use the RichTextBox control rather than a TextBox as it gives you greater selection and formatting capabilities to make highlighting multiple terms easier.

Here's a quick start: http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/34644

Comment: Been there, done that. I was having a problem with being able to paste in formatted text which I was trying to prevent. I also really need more control over the rendering of the highlights.

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same issue. But Incase you didn't know, I'll post this anyway (it's not a complete answer but might get you started.)

You can highlight words by using:

```
int indexOfFoundKeyword = 1;
int lastIndexOfFoundKeyword = 12;
txtbox.SelectionStart = indexOfFoundKeyword;
txtbox.SelectionLength = lastIndexOfFoundKeyword;
```

If you place this inside a button click event and then type about 20 chars and click the button you'll see that you can highlight words in a Metro textbox. The problem that I'm having is getting the start and ending of the found keyword so that I know what values to assign to `SelectionStart` and `SelectionLength` and if I understand your question correctly, I think that's where you're stuck at, too.

## Update

OK, this seems to be a little tempremental but works most of the time. (and accurate when it does work):

```
    // find the word 'jason'.
    string word = "jason";
    int a, b;
    a = genericBox.Text.IndexOf(word);
    b = word.Length;

    genericBox.SelectionStart = a;
    genericBox.SelectionLength = b;
```

If all you are trying to do is find some text, then select it, then this proves that it can be done. Now I know this is not the best way but it's the only way I've been able to get something like this to work in a plain TextBox for metro apps.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could create a control based on the TextBox control or altogether create a custom control. See [here](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2012/03/07/creating-custom-controls-for-metro-style-apps.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh700391.aspx) for more help.